# How can I get userid from an Active Directory user in Sitecore?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sitecore

We're using Active Directory to manage some of the accounts in our Sitecore instance. In the database the usernames are in the `domain\username` format (as you'd expect).

In Sitecore, I can do

```
var user = User.FromName(item["__Created by"], true)
```

and I get back a user object, but I can't seem to get the `Guid` associated with the user in the `aspnet_Users` table.

Other than using AD, we're not doing anything funny with the membership provider.

**Edit:** I probably should have stated: I've got the `ProviderUserKey` but it's not the `UserId` from the `aspnet_Users` table as it would be if this were using the membership provider that comes with Sitecore, it's very different (it's of type `System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference.SecurityIdentifier` if anyone is interested)

Comment: Are you using Active Directory Module and what sitecore version are you using?

Comment: If you're using AD the users aren't imported to the aspnet_users table I believe, and instead you are directly querying against AD (hence the lack of user guid). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We restrict access to various items in the content editor by adding the domain users to the user manager and then restricting from there. So those ones are added to the aspnet_Users table and have a UserId (like if they were added as sitecore\ users). I wanted to get that UserId to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without directly querying the database.  You could write an extension method that queries the database for the User, but I would recommend not using a database field that is intentionally hidden/abstracted by the API.  If you provide more info on why you wanted to get the UserId, we might be able to help you find some alternatives.

Comment: I wanted it because I have a seperate database that I store data in and I wanted to link it to the userid. I might just have to do it so that it uses the username instead. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I usually use either UserName or Email (sometimes they are the same).  I don't typically create an actual foreign key from my table to the membership tables.  Instead I create a utility class and/or extension methods that get the custom data objects for me.

Comment: I'll use that then. Thank you